# new, renew, provide and declare commands naming conventions

Tags: definition, declare

When *defining* new macros (or more general/abstract: resources), we have to consider the case of the macro already being defined. `xparse` handles this (imho) quite nicely, by using the four prefixes

- `\New...`, which throws an error if the control sequence already exists
- `\Renew...`, which throws an error if the control sequence does *not* already exist
- `\Provide...`, which defines the macro if it does not exist, but does nothing in case it exists (and keeps the previous definition)
- `\Declare...`, which defines the macro, regardless of its existence, thus potentially overwriting an existing one.

For the scope of this question, lets call these the `new`, `renew`, `provide` and `declare` mechanism.

One can now note that

- All of the above could be considered *defining* something, so this is probably the right concept to speak of
- As far as I am aware, the decision to not use the `def`, `define` or similar is on purpose, to get away from Texs internal `\def` primitive (which should usually be avoided).
- Numeruous other packages also rely on (some) of these conventions, in particular `new`, `renew` and `provide` always seem to behave as above, at least from the macros I stumbled upon so far.

However, there are also a number of exceptions to this code:

- While LaTeX provides `\newtheorem`, which behaves like `new` in above sense, package `thmtools` chooses `\declaretheorem`, which actually behaves like a `new` mechanism.
- The `acro` package uses `\DeclareAcronym` to mean `new` acronyms.
- There is `\DeclareMathOperator` in the `mathtools` package, which also behaves like `new`
- Package options are introduced with `\DeclareOption`, but also behave like `new`.

So to me it seems like the use of `declare` often rather means `declaring some resource`, as there is no new control sequence for the user to use immediately.

So my question would be what convention I should usually stick to when writing my own packages, especially when it comes to `resources` (in the broadest sense) that my package might provide.

- Are the described `declare` macros just relicts of old code and would probably be considered bad style today?
- Should you rather stick to `\Define...` when doing what `xparse` called `\Declare`? Probably this would also state clear intent on what the macro does.
- Or are there some good arguments why `define` has two different behaviours in different contexts, and if so, how do we judge the context / the correct usage?
- Or should you just not provide `\Declare...` functionality when defining macros (thus reserving Declare for declaring package resources etc), since it is rarely needed and the other three variants `new`, `renew` and `provide` provide better interfaces?
- There is also the notion of `setting`, which the LaTeX3 kernel bundle seems to use heavily. I get that this is a good name for setting control sequences, since you really 'set' some tokens for this control sequence to expand to, but this does not seem an appropriate name when e.g. declaring acronyms etc.

It seems to me that the last three points might be the most relevant. E.g. the `l3kernel` bundle has only two control sequences with `declare` in it (`\text_declare_purify_equivalent:Nn` and `\text_declare_expand_equivalent:Nn`), so the term seems to be rarely used.

I am happy if someone with more experience or a broader view could also just confirm my above considerations, but I wanted to get this struggle out of my head, since I am often unsure which name to pick.

Answer (score 2):

You touch a hot subject, that not only relates to LaTeX, but also many
other computer languages. Groups and companies write their own
style books, to try and solify these conventions. An extreme example
but a good one in my opinion, is Go that enforced many of its conventions
within the language itself (e.g names starting with a capital letter
are global, the rest local). Lua as another example
has groups using different conventions but at least there is one item
they all agree on: that is Classes should be capitalized, but then
it does not really have classes, but prototypes.

On the onset, the best recommendation one can make on naming conventions
is to follow the style of the original language developers.

1. Snakes, pascal-like, camel-case, lowercase, capitals etc.

Variables and functions can be written in many ways, snake_like,
`pascalLike`, `CamelCase`, `lowercase`, `CAPITALS` and David Carlisle-like
`~@#asd:\x/!`, no critisism intented for the latter or the former.

In the backgound what the perception of what is 'right' and 'wrong',
depends on the users and not you. The LaTeX3Team suggests that
code should be divided in three broad levels a) *author level*
b) *template designer* level and c) *programmer* level and this makes
a lot of sense. This is different from many other computer languages,
that almost always adress programmers.

1.1 **The author level**

This is the most important level. It can consist of
one user:that is you, a small team or a very large large number of users.

Users detest unfamiliar territories/comfort zones.

Much has happened since the early 80s. Computer Languages came and went.
Hoare, writing about computer languages wrote:

> A necessary condition for the achievement of any of these objectives
> is the utmost simplicity in the design of the language. Without
> simplicity, even the language designer himself cannot evaluate the
> consequences of his design decisions. Without simplicity, the compiler
> writer cannot achieve even reliability, and certainly cannot construct
> compact, fast and  efficient compilers. But the main beneficiary of
> simplicity is the user of the language. In all spheres of human
> intellectual and practical activity, from carpentry to golf, from
> sculpture to space travel, the true craftsman is the one who
> thoroughly understands his tools. And this applies to programmers too.
> A programmer who fully understands his language can tackle more
> complex tasks, and complete them quicker and more satisfactorily than
> if he did not. In fact, a programmer's need for an understanding of
> his language is so great, that it is almost impossible to persuade him
> to change to a new one. No matter what the deficiencies of his current
> language, he has learned to live with them; he has learned how to
> mitigate their effects by discipline and documentation, and even to
> take advantage of them in ways which would be impossible in a new and
> cleaner language which avoided the deficiency.
>
> It therefore seems especially necessary in the design of a new
> programming language, intended to attract programmers away from their
> current high level language, to pursue the goal of simplicity to an
> extreme, so that a programmer can readily learn and remember all its
> features, can select the best facility for each of his purposes, can
> fully understand the effects and consequences of each decision, and
> can then concentrate the major part of his intellectual effort to
> understanding his problem and his programs rather than his tool.

What does this have to do, with your package/class commands? In a way
you giving your user base a new language (the language of your keys and macros)
the at least give them a bit of familiarity.

1.1.1 If we to follow Hoare's observations then all user commands should be
`CamelCase`, not because is the best, but most users will be familiar with it
and you are following current trends. An all lowercase approach is also
acceptable, but I wouldn't like to mix.

1.1.2 keys:  I like them all to be in lowercase letters and without spaces.
This is a personal preference. This also seems to be the present trend with most packages. I don't  fancy the TikZ/pgf way of using spaces in keys. However, in any
related code I develop with PGF keys, I use spaces to follow conventions. A
better unconventional approach would use dots, instead of spaces. A key
such as `arrow latex` would read better as `arrow.latex`, which by the
way it is a perfectly acceptable name for a key and better than `arrow@key`
or arrow `latex`. Think dots when you lay out the spaces in a key to have
a logical name spacing. Same goes for the `/`  directory-like structures
used for PGF keys.

1.1.3  Specifics

**New**      - ConstructGlobalFunction, CreateCommand

**Provide**  - ConstructIfNotDefined

**Declare**  - Same as New but can be local. You can Declare it many
times.

**Set**      - I setting keys use lowercase \pkgsetkeys{}. Preferably
only one command.

If using different settings commands consider consolidating them into one.

```
       PkgSet{font}{...}
       PkgSet{color}{...}
```

If you do this a lot, maybe you did not `DeclareEnoughKeys`.

Humans like to put things in categories. If you ever watched any
lectures of [Robert Sapolsky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNnIGh9g6fA&list=PLD7E21BF91F3F9683), he has some very convincing arguments
as to why we do this. You can find them at Youtube and they are
worth watching. Since most users would already have internalized,
`New`, `Declare` etc. stick to thes sconvention as much as possible.

1.2 **Template Designer Level**

As above, but in addition you can use lower case commands.

1.3 **Programmer Level**

You should open an API, as to what parts of your code can be used
for the programmer. If you code using LaTeX3 conventions, my suggestion is to
follow them. The convention is to use `l_snake_like_variables_tl:N` with pre and
post attachments to make them unique. This is very similar to Hungarian
naming conventions, and to be honest this style does not have many friends.
However, one needs to appreciate that it is a good solution given the
limitations of the TeX syntax and |expl3| took away a lot of the drudgery of
TeX programming.

**In conclusion your expected user base, should determine the style.**

Comment: I really wonder now whether there is some language in which `~@#asd:\x/!` is valid input.

Comment: @Skillmon In TeX it could be valid input. Define everything as letter and the ~ as the escape character!

Comment: TeX and other syntax-programmable languages don't count!